# Is there a way to have a thread running in the background in a C# ASP.NET Web Forms web application regardless of what page is loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

I'm working on a C# ASP.NET Web Forms application. I need to call an API three times a day and update tables with the data. Is there a way to have a thread running in the background doing this regardless of what page is loaded?

Comment: I would use something like https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: That's interesting, will look into that thanks.

Comment: Hangfire is great. However, ASP.NET great is not a great place for it executing background tasks. The app pool will go idle, and Hangfire therefore won't be running. To fix, [make sure you read their documentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html). Personally our team has decided that Hangfire background job processing should not take place in an ASP.NET app. Instead, we only host the Hangfire dashboard in ASP.NET, and the background job processing happens in a separate Windows Service app.

Comment: Generally seems like a bad idea. Web apps are designed so, apart from stored data, each request from the client is pretty much a whole program run. This is because a user can close the browser window at any moment and 'close' the app, often without the server side noticing it happened. Maintenance like this should be done in a separate service.

Comment: Use a scheduled process instead.  You could start a background thread in the global.asax but I think it's a bad idea. Use a scheduler - like the one in SQL Server - and do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `Task` could do this for you:

```
void MyFabulousApiCall() 
{ 
    // API magic happens here 
}

// Let the task perform your api-calls while your application is running 
bool appIsRunning = true;
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    int callsPerDay = 3;
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var endOfDay = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 23, 59, 59);
    var remainingHours = (endOfDay - now).TotalHours;
    int delayPerCallInMs = (int)(remainingHours / callsPerDay * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    while (appIsRunning)
    {
        MyFabulousApiCall();       
        Thread.Sleep(delayPerCallInMs);
    }
});
```

This example would perform a given action X times a day, beginning with the starting time of your application. Of course you'd still need to cover restarting the task when something went wrong or cancelling the task if you don't need it anymore.

You could put it into your e.g. `Startup.cs` class to make sure that the api-call gets executed right after the apps' start.

If you want to find out more about the`Task` class, look here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task?view=net-6.0

Comment: That's a great answer I think it will be really useful, thanks. I have a follow up question. For context this application has accounts with multiple users per account and the API I'm calling is returning data specific to each account. So could this only work while a user is logged in to their account? Is there a way for the task to run even when a user is not logged in; would putting it in Startup.cs take care of that? I couldn't find Startup.cs but I found a Global.asax file, maybe that's what I need to use?

Comment: oRole your answer worked for me, thank you!